# How to create my own DateStyle?

Tags: postgresql

I want to create my own "DateStyle". In this format "YYYMMDD" no time value.

```
Today: 20141124

Postgres-9.3 on Ubuntu server 14.04.1
```

Comment: There are functions for formatting a date however you like. Do you mean you want this to be the default format whenever you select from the database?

Comment: I do not want to use functions. I want to leave standard "YYYYMMDD". It is an old legacy database that I am converting to Postgres.

Comment: Just to make sure there's no misunderstanding, do you mean you have a legacy application which expects dates to be output in that format, and you are hoping to allow this without modifying the SQL that retrieves them?

Comment: Yes. The original data is in a database where the field size is 8 (YYYYMMDD).

Comment: You can't. You must use `to_char` or similar if you want to do this server-side. The client driver (psqlODBC, PgJDBC, or whatever) is free to transform the result PostgreSQL sends into whatever the application wants, though.